# Space of Riemannian metrics as a topological groupoid

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, groupoids

I'm reading these [notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0611259.pdf) on groupoids and I'm struggling with example 1.4. I recall the relevant definitions below.

---

> **Definition:** A groupoid $\mathcal{G}$ is a small category in which every arrow is invertible.

I will write the same character $\mathcal{G}$ for the set of morphisms and write $M$ for the set of objects, which I will call the base space of the groupoid. Given a groupoid $\mathcal{G}$, we have natural maps $u,s,t,i,m$ where

- $u: M \to \mathcal{G}: x \mapsto 1_x$ where $1_x:x \to x$ is the identity morphism.
- $s,t : \mathcal{G} \to M$ where $s$ sends an arrow to its source and $t$ to its target.
- $i: \mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{G}$ which sends an arrow to its inverse.
- $m:G_2 \to \mathcal{G}$ is the composition of arrows, defined on $G_2 = \{(h,g) \in \mathcal{G}^2: s(h) = t(g)\}$ by $m(h,g) = hg$.

> **Definition:** A topological groupoid is a groupoid $\mathcal{G}$ with base space $M$ such that $\mathcal{G}$ and $M$ are topological spaces, $s,t,u,i,m$ are continuous and additionally $s$ and $t$ are open.

Fix a smooth manifold $N$. We can consider the groupoid whose objects are Riemannian metrics on $N$ which has an arrow from $g_1$ to $g_2$ if and only if there is a diffeomorphism $\phi: N \to N$ such that $g_2 = \phi_* g_1$.

It is claimed in the notes that the compact-open topologies on the space of metrics and diffeomorphisms respectively induce a topology on $\mathcal{G}$ such that $\mathcal{G}$ is a topological groupoid.

> **Definition:** Given topological spaces $X,Y$, the compact-open topology on the space of continuous maps $C(X,Y)$ has subbase given by sets of the form 
>   $$V(K,U) = \{ f \in C(X,Y): f(K) \subseteq U\}$$
>   where $K$ is compact and $U$ is open.

It is not clear to me how the compact-open topology on $\operatorname{Diff}(N)$ induces a topology on $\mathcal{G}$. It is clear that for every $\phi \in \operatorname{Diff}(N)$ and $g \in M$, we have an arrow $\phi_g \in \mathcal{G}$ from $g$ to $\phi_*g$ and in fact all arrows are of this form.

How does the compact-open topology induce a topology on $\mathcal{G}$ and how do we see that this makes $(\mathcal{G},M)$ a topological groupoid?

Comment: Indeed, it is not immediate that the composition is continuous with respect to the c-o topology. It is not hard though and holds for general Hausdorff locally compact topological spaces. One place where it is proven is Ratcliffe's book "Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds". I think he also proves that the inversion is continuous as well but I am not sure.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Do you happen to know where in Ratcliffe's book this is written? The closest I can see is the claim that this a "basic property of the compact open topology ... when $X$ is locally compact" (theorem 5.2.2. in the second edition). Also as far I understand, I'm not actually dealing with the compact open topology on the space of diffeomorphisms directly since the space of morphisms contains more than one arrow for each diffeomorphism. Is this wrong?

Comment: I've found a satisfactory reference for continuity of composition on this site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005754/show-composition-mapping-is-continuous-with-compact-open-topology). Unfortunately it is still unclear exactly how I am viewing my space of morphisms as having the compact-open topology.

Comment: Local compactness is required for the underlying topological space, not for its group of self-homeomorphisms. Unless you are thinking about infinite-dimensional manifolds $N$, it will work for you.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I think you misunderstand my problem. I can see that composition is continuous say from $\operatorname{Diff}(N) \times \operatorname{Diff}(N) \to \operatorname{Diff}(N)$ when everything is given the c-o topology, this is no issue. The problem is that my space of arrows is not $\operatorname{Diff}(N)$ and it is not clear to me how the c-o topology on $\operatorname{Diff}(N)$ is inducing a topology on my space of arrows, as claimed in the notes I link to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to make this thing work. Consider the product space
$$
P= Riem(N)\times Diff(N)\times Riem(N),
$$
where $Riem(N)=M$ is the space of Riemannian metrics on $M$ equipped with the compact-open topology (we think of Riemannian metrics as maps from $M$ to $S^2TM$, the bundle of symmetric 2-tensors on $M$). An isometry $\phi: (N,g_1)\to (N,g_2)$ then is regarded as a triple $(g_1, \phi, g_2)\in P$. Hence, we obtain a topology on the space of morphisms $Mor({\mathcal G})$ in your category as a subspace topology of $P$. The projections
$$
s: (g_1, \phi, g_2)\mapsto g_1, t: (g_1, \phi, g_2)\mapsto g_2
$$ 
are clearly continuous on $P$ and, hence, on $Mor({\mathcal G})$. Let's check that they are also open. For the map $t$:

Fix $\phi_0\in Diff(N)$ and use the fact that there is a continuous section of $t$,
$$
\sigma_{\phi_0}: g_2\mapsto (\phi_0^*(g_2), \phi_0, g_2), Riem(N)\to  Mor({\mathcal G}),
$$
Continuity of this map follows from continuity of the pull-back map
$$
\phi_0^*: Riem(N)\to Riem(N),
$$
which, in turn, is a local "vector calculus" computation.

Then, to verify that $t$ sends a neighborhood $U$ of $p=(g_1^0, \phi_0, g_2^0)$ to a neighborhood of $t(p)$ observe that 
$$
\sigma_{\phi_0}^{-1}(U)
$$
is open and contains $g_2^0= t(p)$.

The proof for $s$ is similar, just use $\phi_0^{-1}$ instead of $\phi_0$. Continuity of $u$  is clear. Continuity of $m$ and $i$ follows from continuity of the composition and inversion maps on $C(N,N)$ (which is the only nontrivial part of the whole story).